# VoIP, SIP, noice reduction, echo cancelation

Tags: delphi, sip, voip

I am tweaking an existing SIP solution for asterisk VoIP. It is working, but it has no sound quality control or no filters to improve the sound on bad lines. I searched google over and over for existing Delphi solutions in this area or some algorithms, but it seems Delphi is very poor here. I know there are commercial libraries out there that offer at least some of this. But I am looking for free source code so I can either use it or do my own implementation of it.

I have already implemented jitter info and jitter buffer. What I am now looking is:

1. Filters: Noise reduction, Echo cancelation...etc
2. Any other means to improve sound when lagging occurs and in general the line quality is bad.

Do any of you have the knowledge where to get any of this? If nothing else you can provide algorithms or other languages code.

P.S

Any solutions I make will be released back to the community. I will release jitter buffer shortly.

Comment: Asterisk has echo cancellation so you could check out the source code for it, although of course it will be in C and not Delphi.

Comment: You can check http://mumble.sourceforge.net/ project.

Comment: Thanks both, but I was hoping for something more then digging through miles of C code.

Answer (score 0):

[SpanDSP](http://www.soft-switch.org/downloads/spandsp/snapshots/) has lots of algorithms for echo cancellation and adaptive dejittering